# Horizontally separate two elements in flex and create a nice border between them

Tags: css, flexbox, border

I need some help in solving this code.
Here I have ingredients and method of preparation next to each other using "flex" in css. Now i want to create a border line between the two in css.
Here is my html:

```html
<main>
<section id="Ingredients">
<p>
<h3> Ingredients: </h3>
    <ul> 
    <li>Eggs (1 per person)</li> 
    <li>Oil</li>
    <li>spices</li> 
    <li>Rice (quantity as required)</li>
</ul>
</p>
</section>

    <section id="Method">
    <h3>Method of Preparation:</h3>
    <p>
<ol> 
    <li> Pour in some oil (as required) &#128512 </li>
    <ul>
        <li> Heat the oil for <span> <em> sometime </em> </span> &#128512</li>
    </ul>
        <li> Now add the egg/eggs &#128512</li>
    <li> Immediately add spices as per your taste &#128512 </li>
    <li> Stir well till all the spices are <span> <em>  well mixed </em> </span> along with the egg/eggs &#128512 </li>
    <li>You can break the eggs into as <span> <em> strips </em> </span> in any size as you like (Don't have to leave them like an omlette) &#128512 </li>
    </p>
    </ol>
    
</section>
</main>
```

Here is my css:

```css
body{
    background-color:palegreen;
    color:maroon;
    padding-left:0px;
}

#intro{
    padding-bottom:30px; 
}

.menu li:hover{
    background-color:mediumaquamarine;
    padding:0 10 0 10;
    }

.menu ol{
    height:50px;
    border-radius:4px;
    background-color:seagreen;
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    line-height:50px;
    font-size:20px;
}

.menu ol li{
    border-radius:15px;
    background-color:peachpuff;
    justify-content:center;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-top:0;
}
h1{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px;
}
#image-heading{
    text-align:center;
}
.PullLine{
    text-align:left;
    color:orangered;
}

main {
    display:flex;
    background-color:papayawhip;
    border-radius:25px;
    justify-content:space-around;
    
}

#ingredients p {
padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:40px;
}

#method{
    border-left:35px;
}
```

I kindly request you help me solve this.

Comment: HTML code is not correct. `</p>` and `</ol>` are placed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```css
#Method{ /* CSS is case-sensetive, remember it */
  border-left: 2px solid orangered; /* Add border */
  padding-left: 10px; /* Add spacing between text and border */
}
```